# Readline: upcase one word backward in insert mode when vi keymap is used

Tags: vim, vi, readline

I always forget to switch CapsLock on when typing words in upper case. I prefer to type a word and then upcase it using bindings in Vim or readline oriented program. It's easyly done in Vim but not in readline.

I use vi keymap and has come to next lines in my `.inputrc`

```
set keymap vi-insert
"\C-a":upcase-word
"\C-z":vi-bword
"\C-l":"\C-z\C-a"
```

So `Ctrl-L` upcase one word backward in insert mode. But it breaks when there are undescores. For example `lc_time` becomes `LC_time`. I can press `Ctrl-A` to upcase next part of the word after underscore but it is tedious.

So is there a way to make it pass over undescores? I can not find readline commands to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried capitalize-word instead of upcase-word?

Comment: @Conner I did. But it only upcases first letter of the word.

Answer (score 1):

`C-a` and `C-z` are already pretty useful, I don't think many people would want to remap them. `"\eu"` is already mapped to the fairly useless (on its own) `upcase-word` which expects you to type a word, move the cursor back to its beginning, and type `M-u`. `upcase-word` does take an argument, though, which can be nice if you need to upcase several words. Try this:

```
# upper case word (default after cursor). alt-(number) for N words
"\eU": upcase-word
# upper case word before cursor.
"\eu": "\e-1\eU"
```

which makes `M-u` upcase one word backwards, while still leaving the option to give an argument with alt-shift-u when one can actually remember that exists. The nice thing is it barely changes the default mapping and won't stomp on any others.

e.g. `do not do that again` `M--` `5` `M-U` will produce `DO NOT DO THAT AGAIN`